# How to prevent flutter app crash on fail to load NetworkImage?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, http-status-code-404, http-error, flutter-image

I checked mon many sources and everybody say to use FadeImage or CachedNetworkimage that got a property to return a Widget in case of error but in my case none of that work and I still don't know what's wrong.
The error I got is "HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, [https://storage.gra.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_4fffdc10a38b40948ec3cab909dd99f3/YeessalStaticProd/7581-3296-2018-03-30.JPG"](https://storage.gra.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_4fffdc10a38b40948ec3cab909dd99f3/YeessalStaticProd/7581-3296-2018-03-30.JPG%22), I know this one is unavailable.
My images are from an API and I can't know if the images I get are available or not.

I thougth this kind of error could be carried using the code I used here :

```
  Widget getImageCover(double width, double height) {
    if (imageCover == null || imageCover!.toString().isEmpty) {
      return Image.asset(
        'assets/no_image.png',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: width,
        height: height,
      );
    }
    return Image.network(
      imageCover!,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.error,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    // return FadeInImage(
    //   image: NetworkImage(imageCover!),
    //   placeholder: AssetImage("assets/no_image.png"),
    //   imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
    //     return Center(
    //       child: Icon(
    //         Icons.error,
    //         color: Colors.red,
    //       ),
    //     );
    //   },
    //   fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    // );
    // CachedNetworkImage img = CachedNetworkImage(
    //   imageUrl: imageCover!,
    //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
    //   width: width,
    //   height: height,
    //   placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
    //     child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    //   ),
    //   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
    // );
    // return img;
  }
```

As you can see in comment of the function I tried many ways to prevent this error but I still get the same error.
I'm really out of solutions right now

UPDATE :
I just noticed that the app crash when I am in launch the app from the IDE with the run button (Is this what is called 'debug mode'?) but when I launch the app directly from my phone (the builded app installed after compilation) the expected behavior happens.

So It "works" but I still don't know why it crash when I launch from the IDE.
Some ideas ?

Comment: That is because your image is not found. I clicked on your image link as says 404, meaning it can not be found. Try to check that the image can be accesible from an explorer in order to check that the image you are trying to use is available. The issue here is not the widget, it is the image itself. Maybe you are lacking a configuration in your storage for the image to be public.

Comment: Actually, I receive images from an API this is one of them. You may understand that I can't really know which image is available or not. That's why I try to control HTTP error. But I know this image is unavailable. I thought there was something I don't know for this situation.

Comment: UPDATE : I tried with FadeImage in the flutter sandbox here : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/network-image and here the error is cached and I see the icon I wanted to see when the image is unavailable. But the same code in my app does not work.

Comment: That's quite strange. Do you have any error logs or something that tells you why is failing while running your app?

Comment: I got the solution. Well actually this is not really a solution, this is quite strange as you said. The app crashes only when I run the app from the IDE with the run button. But once I got the app on my phone and I launch it the behavior expected happen (I can see the placeholder image when the link fail to load). So I don't know why it does this but it "works"

Comment: If you're using VScode just uncheck the uncaught expetions and it will work.

Comment: @AngelRoma This was the problem in my case, I solved it. Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a solution to this problem and I simply had to update the breakpoints settings of Vs code.
[Image of breakpoint settings section on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7354O.png)

I just had to uncheck the '_network_image_io.dart' there and everything worked fine.

Thanks to [Angel Roma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8238354/angel-roma) for his contribution.